# How to pass path of json file as input to parser gson library

Tags: java, json, parsing, path, gson

I want to read in a json file using google's gson library for parsing and reading.

My `*.json` file is located in `src/main/resources`

So I current have this code:

```
JsonElement jElement = new JsonParser().parse(PUT_FILE_PATH_HERE);
```

What would `PUT_FILE_PATH_HERE` be in my case? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Assuming your `resources` is on classpath. You need to give `JsonElement jElement = new JsonParser().parse("/filename.json");`

Comment: @Rp- The overloaded method that accepts a `String` considers that value as JSON.

Comment: Oooh, I did not remember that the `parse(jsoncontent)`. I was assuming OP confused with the path.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must understand that files in `/src/main/resources` should not be considered as resources with file paths. Maven will produce a package for your build where those files should end up on the runtime classpath. They may be in a `.jar`, they may be on a physical file system, etc.

To access resources on the classpath, you use `ClassLoader#getResource(String)` or `Class#getResource(String)` (or `getResourceAsStream(String)`).

In this case, you can use

```
InputStream in = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/yourfile.json");
```

to get an `InputStream`. You can then create an `InputStreamReader` with that `InputStream` and pass it to the `JsonParser#parse(Reader)` method.